# How to get elastic table next to an image?

Tags: css

This is what I want:
http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/4618/myimage.png

This is the best I could come up with:

**CSS**

```
img
{
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

table
{
  background: yellow;
  width: 90%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="40" height="40" />
<table>
  <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
</table>
```

There is a problem with this approach. If you resize browser window at some point the table jumps below the image: [click to view demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2019363/test.htm).

What is the better way of achieving this layout?

Comment: Actually it works perfectly in Firefox

Comment: @Draco Yes, the table jumps only in IE and Google Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try surrounding your table with div like that:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="40" height="40" />

<div style="padding-left:40px">       
  <table> 
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr> 
  </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people might not like tables, but you could use a table with 2 cells that contains your image on the left and the table on the right.

Comment: This also works but there are 13 reasons why CSS is superior to tables in website design: http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design/